# Search for a particular string, extract a number and add few strings below containing that number

Tags: shell, unix, sed, grep

This is how my text file looks:

```
!
hello_group serial_1234
hello-domain serial_1234
!
!
hello_group serial_2345
hello-domain serial_2345
!
```

---

This is how I want to see my result :

```
!
hello_group serial_1234
hello-domain serial_1234
my_content xxxx.1234
my_another_content yyyy.1234
!
!
hello_group serial_2345
hello-domain serial_2345
my_content xxxx.2345
my_another_content yyyy.2345
!
```

---

I want to search for `hello-domain` and in that line grep the number ending after `serial_*`. Store that number in a variable and create my content using that number. Add my ready content below the line `hello-domain`.

I don't know where to start from. Any hint to help me start writing my program are welcome.

Comment: Hi Dorothy... Show us what you've tried, otherwise we'll think we're working for you (for free). You are here to learn, not to make people do your job.

Answer (score 0):

#### Using sed

Try:

```
sed -E 's/hello-domain serial_([[:digit:]]+)/&\nmy_content xxxx.\1\nmy_another_content yyyy.\1/' file
```

For example, with your input data:

```
$ sed -E 's/hello-domain serial_([[:digit:]]+)/&\nmy_content xxxx.\1\nmy_another_content yyyy.\1/' file
!
hello_group serial_1234
hello-domain serial_1234
my_content xxxx.1234
my_another_content yyyy.1234
!
!
hello_group serial_2345
hello-domain serial_2345
my_content xxxx.2345
my_another_content yyyy.2345
!
```

**How it works:**

The sed script consists of a single substitute command:

```
s/hello-domain serial_([[:digit:]]+)/&\nmy_content xxxx.\1\nmy_another_content yyyy.\1/
```

This looks for a line matching `hello-domain serial_` followed by one or more digits, `([[:digit:]]+)`.  Because that regex is in parens, those digits are saved in group 1.

When such a matching line is found, it is replaced with itself, `&`, followed by a newline, `\n`, followed by `my_content xxxx.` followed by group 1, `\1`, followed by a newline, `\n`, followed by `my_another_content yyyy.`, followed by group 1, `\1`.

#### Using awk

```
$ awk -F_ '{print} /hello-domain serial_/{print "my_content xxxx." $NF; print "my_another_content yyyy." $NF}' file
!
hello_group serial_1234
hello-domain serial_1234
my_content xxxx.1234
my_another_content yyyy.1234
!
!
hello_group serial_2345
hello-domain serial_2345
my_content xxxx.2345
my_another_content yyyy.2345
!
```

**How it works:**

- `-F_`

  This makes `_` the field separator.  Because of this, the number that we are interested in will be the last field on a line which, in awk, is denoted `$NF`.
- `print`

  This prints each line to output.
- `/hello-domain serial_/{print "my_content xxxx." $NF; print "my_another_content yyyy." $NF}`

  For any line that matches the regex `hello-domain serial_`, we also print two more lines, each followed by the last field (that is, the number) on the current line.

Comment: Thanks :). One more thing. I tried to copy the result of sed command in another file. But after all "!" I am getting ^M. How to resolve that?

Comment: @DorothyP `^M` are Windows carriage returns. You can remove them with command line tools like dos2unix.

Comment: @DorothyP That indicates that the file was originally a Windows file.  When the sed command is finished, would you prefer that it stay a Windows-format file or would you prefer that it become a Unix-format file?

Comment: Thanks again. Working!